# How to use "interval" in SequelizeJS?

Tags: sequelize.js

I need to convert MySQL query below to SequelizeJS query

```
WHERE createdAt < now() - interval 5 hour
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you achieve above by following.

```
new Date((new Date()).getTime() - 18000000)  //5*60*60*1000
```

5hr = 18000000 Milli Sec

Answer (score 8):

I got it working using `Sequelize.literal`:

```
Model.find({
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
      Sequelize.literal(`created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '5h'`),
    ],
  },
  logging: console.log,
})
```

I would love if anybody could enrich this answer by mixing in `Sequelize.col()` so to automatically get the correct column name inside the literal.